# Without server is it possible to run flask?

Tags: flask

I have a flask application, and I want to run this application in production. Is it possible to do this without your own server and if yes where it is possible?

Comment: are you searching for a PaaS?
an online platform where you can run your web app without taking care of networking, hardware, etc?

Comment: I want to use this website using my own server, If PaaS is doing this one, it is what I want

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can run the flask application through your own webserver such as Apache2 or Nginx hosted in your own server.

Check this out for more info

> https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/deploying/

Comment: So it means my website will be somewhere in cloud yes?

Comment: It depends, if you want to host it in the cloud then yes, the application will be running in the cloud and can be accessed by the users from their local machine by typing the website name.

Comment: what is the other option?

Comment: To host it in your own internal server, which in my sense would be super expensive.